# Python implementation of the Crout matrix decomposition

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a Python implementation of the Crout matrix decomposition which works for 3x3 matrices. I am only allowed to use the numpy package. Here is my attempt so far:

```
import numpy as np

def crout(A: np.ndarray):

    L = np.zeros((3, 3))
    U = np.zeros((3, 3))

    for k in range(0, 3):
        U[k, k] = 1

        for j in range(k, 3):
            sum0 = sum(L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(1, k-1))
            L[k, j] = A[k, j] - sum0

        for j in range(k, 3):
            sum1 = sum(L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(1, k-1))
            U[k, j] = (A[k, j] - sum1) / L[k, k]

    print(" L =", '\n', L, '\n', " U =", '\n', U)
    return L, U

A = np.array([[60.0, 30.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 15.0], [20.0, 15.0, 12.0]])
crout(A)
```

I've tried using my function on the matrix A which should yield:

[image]

but instead gives

[image]

So, clearly the output is wrong. Is my indexing wrong or is there another problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you flipped the j's and k's in the second for loop

```
def crout(A):

    L = np.zeros((3, 3))
    U = np.zeros((3, 3))

    for k in range(0, 3):
        U[k, k] = 1

        for j in range(k, 3):
            sum0 = sum(L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(1, k-1))
            #reversed
            L[j, k] = A[k, k] - sum0

        for j in range(k, 3):
            sum1 = sum(L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(1, k-1))
            U[k, j] = (A[k, j] - sum1) / L[k, k]

    print L
    print U
    return L, U
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only was the indices reversed but there were also some adjustments on the range. The code below returns the expected matrices.

```
import numpy as np

def crout(A):

    L = np.zeros((3, 3))
    U = np.zeros((3, 3))

    for k in range(0, 3):
        U[k, k] = 1 

        for j in range(i, 3):
            sum0 = sum([L[j, s] * U[s, k] for s in range(0, j)]) #range from index 0
            L[j, k] = A[j, k] - sum0 #reversed index

        for j in range(k+1, 3):
            sum1 = sum([L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(0, i)]) #range from index 0
            U[k, j] = (A[k, j] - sum1) / L[k, k]



    print(L)
    print()
    print(U)
    return L, U

A = np.array([[60.0, 30.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 15.0], [20.0, 15.0, 12.0]])
crout(A)
```

Comment: i does not seem to be declared prior to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def crout(A):

    L = np.zeros((3, 3))
    U = np.zeros((3, 3))

    for k in range(0, 3):
       U[k, k] = 1 

        for j in range(k, 3):
            sum0 = sum([L[j, s] * U[s, k] for s in range(0, k)])  
            L[j, k] = A[j, k] - sum0 

        for j in range(k+1, 3):
            sum1 = sum([L[k, s] * U[s, j] for s in range(0, k)]) 
            U[k, j] = (A[k, j] - sum1) / L[k, k]



    print(L)
    print()
    print(U)
    return L, U

A = np.array([[60.0, 30.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 15.0], [20.0, 15.0, 12.0]])
crout(A)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy instead of sum you can use the product of vectors

```
import numpy as np

def crout(A):

    L = np.zeros_like(A)
    U = np.zeros_like(A)
    n = A.shape[0]

    for k in range(n):
        U[k, k] = 1 

        L[k:, k] = [A[j, k] - L[j, :k] @ U[:k, k] for j in range(k, n)]
        U[k, k:] = [(A[k, j] - L[k, :k] @ U[:k, j] ) / L[k, k] for j in range(k, n)]

    return L, U
```

```
A = np.array([[60.0, 30.0, 20.0], [30.0, 20.0, 15.0], [20.0, 15.0, 12.0]])
L, U = crout(A)
print(L@U -A)
```